# Saving an inflated view

Tags: android

I have an activity which inflates TextView, Button from a different XML on a button click. So multiple TextView and Button views are created when it is clicked repeatedly. I would like to save the current state of the layout generated as it is so the next time the app is started, it shows the views that were inflated previously. Currently the inflated views are deleted when the app is restarted.

Is there a way to save the inflated layout?

I tried initializing a boolean before onCreate method.

```
private Boolean b=false;
```

Then set it to True in the onclick method of the button.

Then overrid onSaveInstance method as follows:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
savedInstanceState.putBoolean("inflate", b);
}
```

Then overrid the onRestoreInstanceState method as follows:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
Boolean z = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("inflate");
if (z == true)
     onClick(btn);//Here btn==button view of the button clicked to inflate the layout
}
```

But this does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to save your boolean in SharedPreferences (which will be persistent between the app closing).

The method you are currently (using your onSavedInstance state) will only work when the app is sent to the background (or the screen is rotated when the app is in the foreground).

You cannot (and should not) save the View object - but can easily save the boolean in persistent storage (again SharedPrefences would work great), then re-create the view based on this state.